# Transaction failures are not getting captured in Ajax true client firefox protocol

Tags: loadrunner

I am using LR Ajax trueclient firefox protocol for scripting, in the initial stage what i have observed is transaction failures are not getting captured on certain instances, for example if the script is waiting for a particular object/action to be performed and after a stipulated time let me say 400 secs the session got timed out automatically and its not showing as a transaction failure.

Is there any way to capture these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a b!tch, you need to determine success criteria for the transaction - such as a "completed" or "Passed" tag in the AUT.  Then, Use an "IF" branch structure, and each branch has Evaluate C or Evaluate Javascript, and you close the transaction inside the branches.

Logic is:

```
<Start Transaction>
<do action>
<Wait for object / property>
IF ("Success" found)
<EVAL C> lr_end_transaction({transaction name}, LR_PASS);
else
<EVAL C> lr_end_transaction({transaction name}, LR_FAIL);
```

As to the timeout, you'd have to use Step timeout settings, and then set a "catch error" step, and tell the script how to handle the error.

Yeah, it's a pretty little kludge, but it works.  :-)

I found this online, I'm not the originator - but I've used it and it works.